# systemd stops process even with incorrect ExecStop

Tags: linux, redis, systemd

I'm trying to manage multiple redis instances with systemd. Below is my systemd unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis instances
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/redis/bin/redis-server /home/redis/conf/redis-%i.conf
ExecStop=/home/redis/bin/redis-cli -p %i INFO   # <= INFO should not stop redis process
User=redis
Group=redis

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I could successfully start redis-server by

```
$ sudo systemctl start redis@6379

$ systemctl status redis@6379
● redis@6379.service - Redis instances
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-09-05 17:48:42 JST; 2h 52min ago
 Main PID: 86962 (redis-server)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-redis.slice/redis@6379.service
           └─86962 /home/redis/bin/redis-server 0.0.0.0:6379 [cluster]
```

As a test of stopping redis-server, I intentionally used INFO instead of SHUTDOWN at the ExecStop line.

But when I executed below command, systemd still killed my redis process.

```
sudo systemctl stop redis@6379
```

And there's no output by:

```
sudo journalctl -f -u redis@6379
```

I wonder how could this happen ?

PS:

I replaced redis-cli with an non-exist one:

```
ExecStop=/tmp/nonexist
```

journalctl showed error log like:

```
Sep 05 20:51:57 myhost systemd[96306]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /tmp/nonexist: No such file or directory
Sep 05 20:51:57 myhost systemd[1]: redis@6379.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Sep 05 20:51:57 myhost systemd[1]: Unit redis@6379.service entered failed state.
Sep 05 20:51:57 myhost systemd[1]: redis@6379.service failed.
```

But the running redis process was still killed.

Comment: What does systemctl status redis@6379 show ?

Comment: @Sathiya I updated explanation. I'm pretty sure the process had been launched because I executed redis-benchmark against it.